# Ionic 2, Using Angular 2 Pipe breaks on iOS—"Can't find variable: Intl"

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Experiencing the same problem with the date, percent, and currency pipes when using them in a template—

For example, I'm using a simple percent pipe:

```
{{ .0237| percent:'1.2-2' }}
```

It works when running on Chrome, but when I deploy to an iOS device, it throws this error:

> "EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Intl in [{{ {{ .0237| percent:'1.2-2' }} ..."

Has anyone else run into this problem? Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 69):

That's because it relies on the internalization API, which is not currently available in all browsers (for example not on iOS browser).

See the [compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esintl/).

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3333) (beta.1).

You can try to use a [polyfill for Intl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl).

To do so, you can use the CDN version, and add this to your index.html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.en"></script>
```

Or if you use Webpack, you can install the Intl module with NPM:

```
npm install --save intl
```

And add these imports to your app:

```
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

Comment: i recommend install via npm because if you have network problem then can't access polyfill via internet and app show blank screen

Comment: Add the two import statements to your polyfills.ts if you're using the CLI build setup

Comment: I've been chasing this bug down for days, where ngFor would not refresh correctly on iOS9.3.1.1 because of this JS bug, which I found in Safari. I can confirm what @davidfischer said.

Answer (score 11):

There is a quick fix for this. Add

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.en"></script>
```

to your index.html file before the `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` entry.

See this github answer https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3333#issuecomment-203327903

Answer (score 1):

Or another solution would be writing those pipes yourself. For the date, for example, you can use moment.js, or here is an example for the currency pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'

@Pipe({ name: 'currency' })

export class CurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor() {}

    transform(value: string, currencyString: string ) { 
        let stringOnlyDigits  = value.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
        let convertedNumber = Number(stringOnlyDigits).toFixed(2);
        return convertedNumber + " " + currencyString;
    }
}
```

This pipe is transforming the currency. The percent pipe would work nearly the same way. The regex is filtering all digits including the point for float numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did with RC3. I think it will work with RC4 too.

Create a pipe by typing `ionic g pipe pipe-transform`

Clean the code to remove `@Injectable`. Also, use camel-case to name it like below. Implement `PipeTransform`.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Takes a number and transforms into percentage upto
 * specified decimal places
 *
 * Usage:
 * value | percent-pipe: decimalPlaces
 *
 * Example:
 * 0.1335 | percent-pipe:2
*/
@Pipe({
  name: 'percentPipe'
})
export class PercentPipe implements PipeTransform {
  /**
   * Takes a number and returns percentage value
   * @param value: number
   * @param decimalPlaces: number
   */
  transform(value: number, decimalPlaces:number) {
    let val = (value * 100).toFixed(decimalPlaces);
    return val + '%';
  }
}
```

In your `app.module` add to `declarations` array.

Then in the html use it like in the example usage above.
Here's my example

```
 <ion-col *ngIf="pd.wtChg < -0.05  || pd.wtChg > 0.05" width-25 highlight>
    {{pd.wtChg | percentPipe: 2}}
  </ion-col>
```

Notice I'm using an *ngIf and a highlight directive too in case someone needs extra help. Not necessary obviously.

[image: Resulting image]