# Is it possible to use a pipe in the code?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

When I use my custom pipe in a template, it is like this:

```
{{user|userName}}
```

And it works well.

Is it possible to use a pipe in the code?

I try to use it like this:

```
let name = `${user|userName}`;
```

But it shows

> userName is not defined

My alternative way is using `db.collection.findOne()` manually in the code. But is there any smart way?

Comment: You cannot use template like this, you have to inject the pipe into your contructor

Comment: sorry, i will make it clear. I already inject pipes

Comment: Which pipe you are trying to use in the code? Is this your custom pipe?

Comment: @Siva yes, it is my custom pipe.

Comment: I don't think that you can since `...` isn't executed by Angular. It's ES6 string interpolation...

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-2-use-pipes-in-services

Comment: @Siva wow, it works! thank you so much!

Answer (score 199, accepted):

First declare the pipe in the `providers` of your module:

```
import { YourPipeComponentName } from 'your_component_path';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    YourPipeComponentName
  ]
})
export class YourServiceModule {
}
```

Then you can use `@Pipe` in a component like this:

```
import { YourPipeComponentName } from 'your_component_path';

class YourService {

  constructor(private pipe: YourPipeComponentName) {}

  YourFunction(value) {
    this.pipe.transform(value, 'pipeFilter');
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks nice! But for some reason dependency injection can not inject my pipe into the constructor, even though it can be used in html without problems. It is declared and exported in another module, maybe it needs to be in the providers list, too?  
Creating and using a new instance of MyPipe does work, though. Only DI has a problem...

Comment: @Sam Indeed it need to be in the `providers`. Add `YouPipeComponentName` to your `providers` and this method will work perfectly.

Comment: Also make sure you add it to the correct providers. If you want to use the pipe globally, put it in the app.module providers. If you want to use it only in some lazily loaded modules, put it in their respective module's providers

Comment: Wrong import path. Pipe wont by available under @angular/common

Comment: @Andris I've edited it. It was a mistake. I mean u must import your pipe module.

Comment: Fo anyone using standalone components: you do still need to provide it when the app is bootstrapped in `main.ts` like this: `bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, { providers: [YourPipe] }`

Answer (score 128):

@Siva is correct. And thanks!

So the way to use the pipe in the component is like this:

```
let name = new UserNamePipe().transform(user);
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-2-use-pipes-in-services) to another similar question.

Comment: This works, but it's probably not following Angular best practices / preferred patterns. Passing the pipe into the constructor as a component dependency, as demonstrated in the other answer, is "more right."

Comment: is not there any performance issue using this way? some people might use it all the time!

Comment: This is a completely wrong way of using pipes. Pipes are a **special** purpose classes and should be used via the special means provided by Angular. If you need some functionality implemented in a pipe, but in a way of using it like a regular TypeScript class, then you must create that `regular` class and use it in your TS code (`your-component.ts`, for example). If you need the same functionality in the pipe, you always could use that `regular` class from the pipe as well.

Comment: The biggest difference is that you create more instances of the class with this way. With using the Angular syntax it behaves like a singelton and is just instantiated once.