# Build a Custom maxlength Directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I want to build a custom directive to have the functionality of maxlength. I can not use the default maxlength because i am using ng2-currencyMask, which in turn adds dollar($) and comma(,), sometimes dot(.) to the element. Hence maxlength is considering those characters and does allow to achieve the end result.

Any Suggestions appreciated. It would be better with an example.

By the way, the field is accepting only numbers

Comment: You could use a pipe. A  DecimalPipe or a custum pipe.

Comment: pipe is only to format the display value, rite?

Comment: You can also use the pipe in your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159079/is-it-possible-to-use-pipe-in-the-code-in-angular-2

Comment: will pipe change the model value??