# How to add days to a date in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-moment

I simply want to create a date that is 3 days from now for use in a typescript angular component.

I have looked at [Angular2 moment](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment) but this seems only to relate to pipes. Although I did see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159079/is-it-possible-to-use-pipe-in-the-code-in-angular-2) about using pipes in code, looks a bit hacky...

Maybe I'm missing something as this should be really simple?!

Thanks

Comment: Dates are outside of the concern of Angular or even TypeScript. You can use the built in javascript Date object or use moment.js directly.

Comment: Is this only for display or do you want to do something else with the later date?

Comment: Thanks - yes msanford I want to use it not just for display. 

OK seems I'm barking up the wrong tree and I need to just use the JavaScript Date.

Comment: `... I need to just use the JavaScript Date` <= I prefer moment.js, it's more flexible in many situations and widely supported in many other apis. This is just personal preference though.

Comment: Cool - yes I have used moment in the distant past - seems to be the defacto library for this kind of requirement.

Comment: new Date((new Date()).getTime() + (60*60*24*1000*numberOfDays))

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
date: Date;

ngOnInit() {
  this.date = new Date();
  this.date.setDate( this.date.getDate() + 3 );
}
```

Then you can use the date pipe to display the date nicely in your HTML

```
{{ date | date }}
```

Which renders thusly:

> Sep 25, 2017

Comment: But this is not working with daylight saving time countries. How to get correct dates in other countries?