# date function in angular - I want to increment the date by 7 and display in html

Tags: angular, typescript, date-pipe

i have a date in this format from API **31-08-2021 13:58**
I want to show this date in one mat-cell and then in another cell
I have to add 7 to it eg: **7-09-2021 13:58** and display this
how to achieve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368986/how-to-add-days-to-a-date-in-angular2 it might help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your ts file.

```
  date = new Date();
  nextDate = new Date();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.nextDate.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 7);
  }
```

date - Current Date(can be your date from API response)

nextDate - date + 7 i.e next 7th day.