# Bind angular pipe to a dynamically created HTML element

Tags: angular, angular6, pipe, blob, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to display a blob image. In IE 11 it is not supported and displays a broken image, so I have created a pipe which converts blob image to base 64.

Is there a way where I can bind this pipe to a newly created image element ?

Following code doesn't seem to be working,

```
const uploadedImgElement = document.createElement('img');
uploadedImgElement.src = response.data.attachmentDetails.fileFullPath + '| blobToBase64';
```

where `blobToBase64` is a pipe.

Comment: constructor(private pipe: YourPipeComponentName) {}

  YourFunction(value) {
    this.pipe.transform(value, 'pipeFilter');
  }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159079/is-it-possible-to-use-pipe-in-the-code-in-angular-2

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the Pipe inside of your Component

```
@Component({
  ...,
  providers: [ BlobToBase64Pipe ]     // Declare it here
})
export class SampleComponent implement OnInit {

  // Add it on your constructor 
  constructor(private blobToBase64Pipe: BlobToBase64Pipe) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    ...

    const filePath = response.data.attachmentDetails.fileFullPath; 

    // Perform your pipe transform here
    const convert = this.blobToBase64Pipe.transform(filePath);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also refer to this sample to add an image element in Angular application:

html code:

```
<div id="div_container">

</div>
```

Component.ts:

```
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer) { }
  ngOnInit() {

    const newimage = document.createElement("img");
    newimage.src = this.base64Image;
    document.getElementById("div_container").innerHTML = newimage.outerHTML;

  }

  base64Image='data:image/png;base64, base64data';
}
```

The screenshotas like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3Vp0.png).