# Angular : Using pipe inside ts not in html

Tags: angular, pipe

I have a pipe that returns a css string depending on value coming form data json .

Main components

```js
this.coords.push(new L.Marker([i.lat, i.lng], {
  rotationAngle: i.heading,
  rotationOrigin: 'bottom center',
  icon: new L.DivIcon({
    html: `<div style="width: 65px;";>
             <img src="assets/icon/airplan.jpg" style="width: 20px;height: 25px;" ngClass='${i.heading}| heading'/>
           </div>`
  })
}).addTo(this.map)
```

The problem is when i run my project l get only same output of pipe name , l mean looks like pipe doesn't work !
Output

```html
<img src="assets/icon/airplan.jpg" style="width: 20px;height: 25px;" ngclass="272|heading">
```

Any idea please

Comment: If it's in TS why not just use a function instead of a pipe? Something like `<img src="assets/icon/airplan.jpg" style="width: 20px;height: 25px;" ngClass='"+this.calcHeading(i.heading)+"'/>`

Comment: because value of heading is numbers and you know css is not Acceptance number like `.12{}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use a pipe in the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159079/is-it-possible-to-use-a-pipe-in-the-code)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-use-pipes-in-services-and-components) is also helpful.

Comment: Maybe also post the code of your pipe because you are saying it returns css, in that case consider using `[ngStyle]`. Also note that `[ngClass]` and `[ngStyle]` expect objects as value. Like `[ngStyle]="{'width': someVar}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the `ngClass` without the `${}` brackets?

```
[ngClass]='i.heading | heading'
```

Otherwise you can run the pipe inside the component class:

You can inject your pipe inside the constructor and run the transform function

```js
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private headingPipe: HeadingPipe) {}

  transformedHeading(heading: string) {
    return this.headingPipe.transform(heading);
  }
}
```

and in your template

```
<img [ngClass]="transformedHeading(i.heading)"/>
```

Comment: @AliGhassan `ngClass` wont be working because angular wont be rendering that part of code. Instead `Leaflet` injecting that template it self..

Comment: Thank you  . you saved me . Name of css class now is showing in nglcass but he doesn't apply . any idea why ?  See image [https://i.ibb.co/QP1X3gY/Capture.png]

Comment: Can you try replacing `[ngClass]` by `class`? Please remove the square brackets, too.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you use `ngClass='...'` instead of `[ngClass]='...'`.

With the former, your string is passed as is without evaluation. With the latter (with `[]`), your statement is actually evaluated - and the pipe will be taken into account.

Comment: l did that before but still same problem

Comment: Then your pipe is not imported in your component's module

Answer (score -2):

use like this

```
<img src="assets/icon/airplan.jpg" style="width: 20px;height: 25px;" [ngclass]="272|heading">
```

Now pipe will return what have you have wanted.