# How to populate html table value conditionally with date pipe?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a table value as a date.

```html
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="lastModificationDate">
    <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef fxFlex="30%">Last Modification Date</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let subgroup" fxFlex="30%">{{employee.lastModificationDate | date: 'dd MMM yy HH:mm'}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

This pipe is working for me good, but in some cases the date value is coming as *null*. In this case I want to populate it as "N/A".

so I need something like:

```
{{employee.lastModificationDate = null ? | date: 'dd MMM yy HH:mm' : 'N/A'}}
```

How can I do this optional operation with date pipe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript)

Comment: I think there is a pipe function that you can use on typescript. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159079/is-it-possible-to-use-a-pipe-in-the-code

Comment: Why not just add two `mat-cell`s, each with a `*ngIf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following syntax with the ternary operator:

```
{{ !!myDate ? (myDate | date:'dd MMM yy HH:mm') : 'N/A' }}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvdcmo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo