# Formatting date inside of component (ionic)

Tags: date, ionic-framework, appery.io

Im working an app with appery.io platform using ionic 1
I have a date value inside of text component.

If I use:

```
{{user.user_date}}
```

Return

```
{"$date":"1958-12-08T00:00:000Z"}  // Correct value but wrong format
```

If I use:

```
{{user.user_date | amDateFormat:'DD/MM/YYYY'}}
```

Return

```
22/01/2021 // today date
```

How can I format this date value inside of component?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `format this date value inside of component` ? Do you mean inside the `component.html` or `component.ts` file or something different ?

Comment: Ionic 1 uses AngularJS? Read this then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131553/angularjs-convert-dates-in-controller

Comment: hi,
component.ts

Comment: But the solution can be in javascript then I pass the value to the component

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be summarize as "How to use a pipe in a Typescript file". Where your can find the solution here [Is it possible to use a pipe in the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159079/is-it-possible-to-use-a-pipe-in-the-code)

You need to import the pipe `amDateFormat` in the `providers` of your module. Then, you need to inject the pipe in the constructor of the component. Finally call the transform function of the pipe.

```js
constructor(
    private datePipe: DatePipe
    ) {
    return this.datePipe.transform(user.user_date, "DD/MM/YYYY");
}
```

You need to change `DatePipe` with the name of the pipe you as using. The code works in the last version of Ionic/Angular, not tested in Ionic 1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to watch appery.io youtube video how to work with pipe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzMiIKeaJcc

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to have the solution outside of StackOverflow.