# Angular currency pipe for -0 value

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface, frontend, pipe

I am using Angular currency pipe to show the amount with currency code transformed according to the locale. It is working as expected. Only in the case of -0 amount it is removing the -ve sign after transforming the amount. Is there a way to show the -0 amount according to a locale with a -ve sign?

Example,
For -0 in en-GB locale -
The actual output is EUR 0.00
The expected output is EUR -0.00

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to display the `-`

Comment: Its a business requirement to show it. This amount is to be subtracted from a particular amount. No matter what the amount is.

Comment: It would be a big of a hack, but I imagine you could make a pipe that does something like this: `value === 0 ? currency(-1).replace('1', '0') : currency(value)`

Comment: Maybe you can create a custom pipe. You can extend the CurrencyPipe while you create your pipe. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971085/extend-a-pipe-like-currency-or-number-on-a-custom-pipe-on-angular2

Comment: @JLRishe, I could do that in the same pipe. Thanks.