# Apply pipe or filter only for specific type of data -Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material, formatdatetime

```
<span class="date_value">{{SelectedDateText }}</span>
......
....
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker"  [(ngModel)]="SelectedDateText"  >
......
```

The data type of "SelectedDateText" is string and it is also having string values in some cases like 'Today', 'Yesterday'. but when date is selected from matDatepicker it shows data in (Tue Feb 27 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)). I Can not apply filter on SelectedDateText as it is also containing strings. How can I manage to apply filter only when value is in date datatype or something else like this

Comment: Please show more code, especially where `SelectedDateText` is defined and its value assigned.

Comment: You can just apply the filter to any kind of value and check the type of value in the filter logic itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like (with courtesy of [Angular2 use basic pipe in custom pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808272/angular2-use-basic-pipe-in-custom-pipe) )

EDITED after comment

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {DatePipe} from "@angular/common";

@Pipe({name: 'myDatePipe'})
export class MyDatePipe extends DatePipe
{
        transform(value: any, format?: string, timezone?: string, locale?: string): string {
        if (typeof value === "string") {
            return value; // return raw string
        } else {
             return super.transform(arguments); // use the inherited datePipe transform method
        }
    }
}
```

should do the trick

Comment: Do you have to implement PipeTransform, since DatePipe already implements it?