# Angular6 Getting error while trying to using DecimalPipe to a custom pipe

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, angular2-custom-pipes

I am trying to inject `DecimalPipe` to my custom pipe as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35810607/5400597).

here is the code:

```
@Pipe({name: 'irc'})
export class IRCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {}

  transform(value: string | number, type: string = 'rial') {
    value = Number(value);
   if (isNaN(value)) { throw new Error(`${value} is not a acceptable number`); }
    return this.decimalPipe.transform(value, '1.0-0') + ' ریال';
  }
}
```

But I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined` error when running tests from this code.

I also tried extending the `DecimalPipe` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35808488/5400597)
:

```
@Pipe({name: 'irc'})
export class IRCurrencyPipe extends DecimalPipe implements PipeTransform {


  transform(value: string | number, type: string = 'rial') {
    value = Number(value);
    if (isNaN(value)) { throw new Error(`${value} is not a acceptable number`); }
    return super.transform(value, '1.0-0') + ' ریال';
  }
}
```

But I get: `Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'` in this case.
Is there a working solution to using one of the built-in pipes in angular to a custom pipe?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: I did something else. You can see code [here](https://github.com/alihoseiny/ngx-persian/blob/master/projects/ngx-persian/src/lib/Pipes/IRCurrency.pipe.ts).

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you don't have `LOCALE_ID` set.
You can set it like this:

```ts
import { LOCALE_ID, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from '../src/app/app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr' } ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

See [full docs here](https://angular.io/guide/i18n)

Comment: Thanks, but I've added that to providers before and it did not help me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried and I am getting the result. See the code

```js
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'currency'})
export class CurrencyPipe extends DecimalPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string | number, type: string = 'rial') {
        value = Number(value);
        if (isNaN(value)) { throw new Error(`${value} is not a acceptable number`); }
        return super.transform(value, '1.0-0') + ' ریال';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it is the code that I tried. The problem is it only works when I make an instance of it with `en-US` input to the constructor. But I wanted to use `fa` value for it if I had to do it.

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz of it and share it.

Answer (score 0):

In your unit test you'd need to register any non-default locale (additionally to providing `LOCALE_ID`):

```
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';

beforeEach(() => {
  registerLocaleData(localeFr);
});
```

See https://angular.io/guide/i18n#i18n-pipes