# Using - new DatePipe() - in TypeScript throws an error

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to properly use `new DatePipe()` with TypeScript but I'm getting the following error: `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

So when I try to compile this `new DatePipe().transform(date, 'dd.MM.yyyy')` it fails.

**Edit**

I import `DatePipe` like this: `import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';`

Comment: You're not supposed to create an instance of DatePipe by yourself. Inject it instead.

Comment: @JBNizet How? I've tried to do this in my constructor: `constructor(private datePipe:DatePipe){` and used `this.datePipe.transform(date, 'dd.MM.yyyy')` but it fails as well

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"? What happens precisely? Have you added it to the providers of your NgModule?

Comment: @JBNizet When I say it fails I mean I get the same error: `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.` and yes, I've added `DatePipe` in my module declaration

Comment: Then you haven't injected it. You're still using new DatePipe(). Post your new code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607568/cannot-instantiate-datepipe/39608753#39608753

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, it did work but took some time for my editor to update!