# Angular2 - DatePipe raising error in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a date like so

```
var d = new Date();
var date = new DatePipe().transform(d,'yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss');
```

However TypeScript raises the following error

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Am I missing a parameter or passing them in the wrong way?

Any advice would be great.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607568/cannot-instantiate-datepipe

Comment: Cheers found my answer in there!

Answer (score 0):

After checking out the link in the first comment posted above, it turns out you have to specify the locality when instantiating like so

```
var date = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(d,'yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss');
```