# TypeScript: Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined in datepipe.transform

Tags: angular, date, typescript

How can I resolve this problem?
I have a typescript method when I get the kekeh/ngx-mydatepicker date and transform to string.

this is my class:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'

export class DateUtils {

public static getMyDatePickerDateToString(myDate: any): string {

    let datepipe: DatePipe;
    var date = new Date(myDate.date.year, myDate.date.month, myDate.date.day);

    return datepipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
  }
}
```

and here is my error:

```
ERROR
TypeError: Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined
```

Comment: You did not define `datepipe`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a new `DatePipe` object. The first line of your `getMyDatePickerDateToString` method you declare `datepipe` but you don't actually instantiate one.  I'm not familiar with the `DatePipe` API but it is probably something like

```
const datepipe: DatePipe = new DatePipe();
```

Comment: You are right, because your answer, I've found the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607568/cannot-instantiate-datepipe

Answer (score 4):

You need to create an instance to it and pass param like below. In my case I need to pass param to it to resolve the issue

```
protected datePipe: DatePipe = new DatePipe('en-US')
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 4, I faced the same issue.

This is the fix :

```
 private datePipe: DatePipe = new DatePipe();
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line in constructor and it worked for me

constructor(private datepipe: DatePipe) {}