# Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined

Tags: angular, unix, ionic-framework, ionic2

Why is it that im having such error when i integrated and declared the datepipe properly.

```
 import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

 @Component({
 selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
 })
 export class HomePage 
 {
datepipe: DatePipe;

     getItems(ev: any) {

   console.log((this.datepipe.transform(ListOfitems[1].fromDate,'mediumDate')));
```

}

Comment: i think you should use date pipe with "new" syntax: new DatePipe('en-US').transform(rec.key, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))

Comment: `this.datepipe` is not even initialized.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806698/typescript-cannot-read-property-transform-of-undefined-in-datepipe-transform

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript: Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined in datepipe.transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806698/typescript-cannot-read-property-transform-of-undefined-in-datepipe-transform)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use injection in your component:

```
constructor(private datepipe: DatePipe) {}
```

Then:

```
console.log(this.datepipe.transform(ListOfitems[1].fromDate,'mediumDate'));
```

Don't forget to add the pipe to your providers in your module:

```
providers: [
    ...,
    DatePipe,
]
```

Comment: hi what if the date is not correct what should i do? it gives me jan 18 1970 and the correct one is feb 7 2017?

Comment: I think that's another issue (meaning another question). Maybe `ListOfitems[1].fromDate` has a wrong value?

Comment: multiplying to *1000 will give you the correct date