# Custom directive to convert percent

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

hello guys I am trying to create a custom directive in angular 2 which will change the value of an input ngModel to percent for example

number / 100

[image: example image]

this is an example image of what I am trying to achieve.

For example the user sees the 5.12 but the value that will be send in the back end should be 5.12 / 100, but the user doesn't see this

I have come to an approach but I think that is a wrong approach can you guys help me out.

this is my [`code`](https://plnkr.co/edit/7QsyP58Zw2X5GokEDanu?p=preview).

for example:

when it comes from backend to be multiplied by *100 and when it goes to backend to be divided by /100

Comment: [implement a custom `ControlValueAccessor`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254077/angular-2-date-pipe-inside-a-formcontrol-input/42254218#42254218) The question is about dates, but that's the same approach.

Comment: @n00dl3 I was thinking for that too, would that make me any problems if than later comes to dynamic content ?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic content" ?

Comment: @n00dl3 for example if I have to handle events in the custom input

Comment: the custom input is a directive or a component, so you are free to do what you want regarding event handling, even creating custom ones if needed. Note that DOM events are bubbling, so even in a really complex component, you will be able to "catch" them from the outside world...

Comment: Add the code inside question rather than providing link. That will help community help you better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, forwardRef, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NgModel } from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
    selector: '[ngModel][toPercentage]',
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => ToPercentDirective),
        multi: true
    }],
    host: {
        "[value]": 'ngModel',
        '(blur)': 'onBlur()'
    }
})
export class ToPercentDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    private innerValue: string;
    private toNumber: number;
    private toPercent: number;

    public onChangeCallback: any = (_) => { console.log(_) }
    public onTouched: any = () => { /*Empty*/ }

    onBlur() {
        var input = this.el.nativeElement.value;
        this.toPercent = parseFloat(input) / 100;

        if (input != this.toNumber) {
            this.onChangeCallback(this.toPercent);
        }
    }

    get value(): any {
        console.log(this.innerValue);
        return this.innerValue;
    };

    //set accessor including call the onchange callback
    set value(v: any) {
        if (v !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = v;
            this.onChangeCallback(v);
        }
    }

    writeValue(val: string): void {
        // this.ngModel.ControlValueAccessor.writeValue(val);
        this.toNumber = parseFloat(val) * 100;
        this.el.nativeElement.value = this.toNumber;
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        // console.log(fn);
        this.onChangeCallback = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        // console.log(fn);
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }
}
```

I am posting this answer for anyone facing a similar issue.

it handles this problem:
converts a number * 100 when it comes from backend
and converts a number / 100 when it sends to backend.

but the user doesn't see these operations.

for example:

```
response  = 0.5

toNumber = 0.5 * 100 -> <input number> 50 
toPercent= 50 / 100 -> <input number> 50, value = 0.5
```

hope it helps anyone

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be of some use.

https://blog.ngconsultant.io/custom-input-formatting-with-simple-directives-for-angular-2-ec792082976

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `EventEmitter` to directive that outputs the changed value, but you shouldn't change the `ngModel` value in the directive. The `[ngModel]="employerShare"` that should be added to the component to hold the percentage value.

This is [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cPF1iGZZtotjpm1inqh8)

#### ToPercentageDirective:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][toPercentage]',
  providers: [NgModel],

})
export class ToPercentageDirective implements OnInit {


@Output() sharedVarChange = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, 
              private ngModel: NgModel) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let that = this;
    let toPercent:any;


    this.ngModel.valueChanges.subscribe(function (value){
      toPercent = value / 100;

      // that.ngModel.update.emit(toPercent);
      that.sharedVarChange.emit(toPercent);
    });


    // $(that.el.nativeElement.value).bind(function(newVal){
    //     newVal = toPercent;
    //     that.ngModel.update.emit(newVal);

    //     console.log(newVal);
    // });

  }


  // @HostListener("focus", ["$event.target.value"])
  // onFocus(value) {
  //   this.elementRef.nativeElement.value  = this.convertPercentage(value);
  // }

  // onInputChange(event) {
  //   console.log('Change');
  // }

  // @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])
  // onBlur(value) {
  //   this.elementRef.nativeElement.value  = this.convertPercentage(value);
  // }

  convertPercentage(number){
        return number / 100;
    }

}
```

#### App component:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Example</h2>

      <form>

        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="employerShare" required
                            name="data.insObj.stat['AHV,IV,EO'].employerShare" placeholder="5.125%"
                                    [ngModel]="employerShare"
                                    (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" 
                                    toPercentage 
                                    (sharedVarChange)="onSharedVarChange($event)">


      </form>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  employerShare: number;
  data = {};

  constructor() {

  }

  onChange ($event){
    console.log("onChange: " + $event);

  }

  onSharedVarChange ($event){
    this.data.employerShare = $event;
    console.log("onSharedVarChange: " + this.data.employerShare);

  }
}
```