# Angular 4 combine orderBy and translate pipe

Tags: angular, angular-translate, angular-pipe

I have the following:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of array | orderBy: 'type'">
      {{ item.type | translate }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The `i18n translation` is made inside the `li` block. Then, no matter what the translation is, the `orderBy` pipe does not care of the language to sort the array.

How can I order in the specific language?

- do something like: `let item of array | translate: 'type' | orderBy: 'type'`
- use the `translate` pipe into the `orderBy` pipe
- translate the array in the controller and then use the `orderBy` sort

Comment: why don't you write your custom pipe using pipe transform and implement logic for both these pipes in a single one like one in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-2-use-pipes-in-services.