# How to use Angular number pipe in Component and Service

Tags: angular

I use below number pipe to format quantity:

```
{{tradcollapse?.quantity | number}}
```

example show as `1,234,0`.

I want to use this format quantity in Component with filtered, not a number with as it is 12340.
How can I implement it?

Answer (score 15):

In case someone else needs to do this, you now have to import DecimalPipe instead of NumberPipe.

e.g.

```
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
```

Then transform 
e.g.

```
// Format cost amount to currency to improve readability of number.
formatToCurrency(r) {
  let val = this.decimalPipe.transform(r.get('Amount').value, '1.2-2')
  r.get('Amount').setValue(val);
}
```

Comment: I found that I also had to add the pipe in my app.module providers: `providers: [DecimalPipe]`

Comment: You can add it directly to the component directive too. Also do not forget to add it to the constructor :P

Answer (score 11):

You can try with formatNumber function Angular 8.

```
import { formatNumber } from '@angular/common';
```

//wherever is needed

```
console.log(formatNumber(this.numberValue,"en-US", "1.2-3"));
```

Refer https://angular.io/api/common/formatNumber

Answer (score 2):

```
import { NumberPipe } from '@angular/common';

class MyService {

  constructor(private numberPipe : NumberPipe ) {}

  transformNumber(number) {
    this.numberPipe .transform(number);
  }
}
```

something like this , or take help from

[Angular 2/4 use pipes in services and components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-2-4-use-pipes-in-services-and-components)

Comment: the version is  "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.2" , has no exported member 'NumberPipe' . there is a another way?

Comment: try to use as : new NumberPipe().transform(number);

Comment: it doesn't work , may be NumberPipe dont support on AngularJS 2 rc version?

Comment: @VictorGuan you should not use the rc.2 version of angular when the current stable version is 4.2.5. Start by changing that. rc2 is completely obsolete. Thenread the documentation: https://angular.io/api?type=pipe the name of the pipe is DecimalPipe, not NumberPipe.

Comment: @JB Nizet this is a place in a stopgap using rc.2 version , will upgrade version in coming day.in addition to , it does works with DecimalPipe, thank you your kindness.