# Angular date format with if condition

Tags: angular, datetime, if-statement, angular-ng-if

I have following angular:

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.getInfo().then((data) => {               
        this.allInfo= data;           
    });
};
```

...where the `data` looks like below:

```
0:
  Time: 1508218791131
1:
  Time: 1508217179413
2:
  Time: 1508217026810
```

Then, in html:

```
<div *ngFor = "let each of allInfo;" >
    <div>{{ each.Time | date : "shortTime" }}</div>
</div>
```

These works just fine.

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

I am trying to compare the `Time` to the `current time` with two conditions:

1. If it has been **less** than 24 hours compared to the current time, then use "shortTime" giving `11:10 pm`
2. If it has been **more** than 24 hours compared to the current time, then use "MMM d" giving `Oct 16`.

How do I add the if condition to the syntax inside of ngFor?

Answer (score 2):

You have to possible paths:

- modify `this.allInfo` to have the format that you want using $filter inside the controller instead that directly inside the template. Look at [Angular 2/4 use pipes in services and components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-2-4-use-pipes-in-services-and-components).
- make a custom filter that does what you want. Not recommended since filters are meant to encapsulate presentation logic across contexts.