# do not approximate number pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, pipes-filters

I have this code:

```
"ValorPesos" : 345224.2666860273

<td class="numberAlign-right">{{valorCuota.ValorPesos | currency:code:'CLP':'1.4-4'}}</td>

Current ouput: 34.5224,2667
What i want: 34.5224,2666
```

Is there any way that the number pipe do not approximate the number?

I didn't saw anything like that in Angular docs.

Comment: it's following standard rounding rules, if you want your own rounding rules, then put a custom roundDown pipe before the currency pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick work around, you can increase the `minFractionDigits` and `maxFractionDigits` by **1** and slice the resultant string to exclude the last character by

```
unRoundedCurrency = roundedCurrency.slice(0, -1);
```

To accomplish this, you can create a function in component and return the resultant currency string from there, after applying angular's currency pipe using the method described below.

[How to use angular pipe from component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-2-4-use-pipes-in-services-and-components)