# How to use pipes in Component

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I want to use the datePipe in my component. I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-2-4-use-pipes-in-services-and-components) but I am met with

```
Error: StaticInjectorError[DatePipe]: 
StaticInjectorError[DatePipe]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for DatePipe!
```

Here is my code:

**Component**

```js
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

export class LivePreviewComponent implements OnInit{
    currentDate = new Date();     
  
    constructor(private datePipe:DatePipe) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.datePipe.transform(this.currentDate, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 66):

Add to providers array in the component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: '...',
    providers:[DatePipe]
})
```

or inject it to module

```
@NgModule({
    providers:[DatePipe]       
})
```

or write a separate class extending the DatePipe and use it as a service

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomDatePipe extends DatePipe {
  transform(value, format) {
    return super.transform(value, format);
  }
}
```

and inject this to providers array

```
@Component({
        selector: 'app-root',
        templateUrl: '...',
        providers:[CustomDatePipe]
    })
```

Comment: I just had the biggest facepalm. Thank you.

Comment: only the component works in angular 7. all the other ones cause errors

Comment: @PriyankaArora  happy to help you :)

Answer (score 11):

Add in the Module `providers: [DatePipe],`

Add in the constructor `private datePipe: DatePipe`

Add in Ts file for Form Array:

```
const start_date = this.datePipe.transform(starttime, 'hh:mm a');
const end_date = this.datePipe.transform(endtime, 'hh:mm a');
this.Form.controls['starttime'].patchValue(start_date);
this.Form.controls['endtime'].patchValue(end_date);
```