# angular - Angular 6 how to I edit date format?

Tags: angular, date, format

```
        <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns">
      <ng-container *ngIf="column.isModelProperty" [matColumnDef]="column.property">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ column.name }}</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <span class="fury-mobile-label">{{ column.name }}</span>
          {{ row[column.property] }}
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>

export class Senderv2 {
    serviceCode: string;
    insertDate : DatePipe;

    constructor(senderv2) {
        this.serviceCode = senderv2.serviceCode;
        this.insertDate = senderv2.insertDate;
    }
}

export class ListColumn {
  name?: string;
  property?: string;
  visible?: boolean;
  isModelProperty?: boolean;
  displayFn: any;
}
```

The data comes from the database to the table. Data type datetime in the database
Column property insertDate how to I edit date format?

Comment: do you mean edit the date itself in the DB? Or display the date in a custom format at template?

Comment: @Vojtech I want display the date in a custom format at template (mat-table) column insertDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit you date in a custom format by using Angular's **DatePipe**.

Have attached a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-component-date-pipe)** for your reference

Sample Illustration:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';


class Sender {

     currentDate: any = new Date();    

     constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}   // Be sure to import this as a provider either inside Component or on your Module

     transformDate() {
         this.currentDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.currentDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');  // 2018-11-23
     }

}
```

you can also refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47783402/6891406) for more information about implementing **DatePipe**

Comment: Thank you very much.

I solved.

    constructor(senderv2, datePipe: DatePipe) {
        this.insertDate = datePipe.transform(senderv2.insertDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
    }

Comment: How can you do this? datePipe.transform returns a string, not a date, it should be giving you assignment error

Comment: @Dseaster Hi, have attached a working Stackblitz demo for your reference :)