# How to filter a unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

so basically I have an ionic mobile application which has a search button or filter feature. I already figure out how to filter the words but the problem here is that the date since it is a timestamp and is displayed in the app through
angular date filter which is

```
<p>at {{item.fromDate | date:'mediumDate'}}</p>
```

Here's a picture for you to picture out.

[image]

Data that is displayed. As you can see the fromDate and toDate are Unix timestamp

[image]

so the problem here is that i wanted to do a search feature for dates but I'm having a hard time as to how since it is a timestamp.

here's is my code for the filter

```
getItems(ev: any) {
  console.log("awdaw");
  console.log("awdaw",this.ListOfitems);
  console.log("otin");

  this.ListofItems();
  let val = ev.target.value;
  if (val && val.trim() != '') {
    this.ListOfitems = this.ListOfitems.filter((ListOfitem) => {
      return (ListOfitem.fromAddress.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1||
        ListOfitem.toAddress.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) >-1) ;


    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the `mediumDate` filter in your filter function.

For this, you have to use `DatePipe`:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

You have to inject this in your class. You can see how in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35152297/2056593).

Then just:

```
this.datePipe.transform(ListOfItem.fromDate, 'mediumDate')
this.datePipe.transform(ListOfItem.toDate, 'mediumDate')
```

It should return the same string that you are showing

So the additional conditions you have to add to your filter is:

```
this.datePipe.transform(ListOfItem.fromDate, 'mediumDate').toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
this.datePipe.transform(ListOfItem.toDate, 'mediumDate').toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
```

By the way, you can do something like this:

```
const val = (ev.target.value || '').toLowerCase();
```

So you don't repeat yourself by writing `val.toLowerCase()`

Comment: hello, may i ask what $filter is?

Comment: because im using typescript hehe

Comment: In angularjs (v1) $filter can be injected in your controllers/services/factories to call the same filters that you use in views. Are you using angular2+ right?

Comment: yes, i understand the logic but im havin a hard on how to use $filter. without it (ListOfItem.fromDate, 'mediumDate') thiss wont work since this is the html binding format.  when using filter it gives me $filter not defined.

Comment: i think htis is the best way but im having a hard time on $filter. hehe sorry im beginner to angular

Comment: Updated my reply to angular2+. My old answer was using angular version 1.x, now it uses angular2+

Comment: hi. can i ask whats the possible reason for cannot read property of transform undefined?

Comment: imported import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'; then declared datepipe: DatePipe;

Comment: Are you injecting it? Another way (not recommended but that should work) is to use: `let toDateText = new DatePipe().transform(ListOfItem.toDate, 'mediumDate');`

Comment: Or define a local variable `const datePipe = new DatePipe()` and then just  `datePipe.transform(ListOfItem.toDate, 'mediumDate')`