# Use pipes in components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, pipe

I found this solution here:

[Angular - Use pipes in services and components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-use-pipes-in-services-and-components)

This solution is great, but I want to know if there is a way to use a custom pipe in the template of that custom Component as per example:

```
`<div *ngFor=" something of someThings | customPipe: value">
</div>`
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please post code, or a [mcve], or anything that could help identify your issue or your request. Right now, I have no idea what you're talking about, except that you want to use a pipe in a component. And if so, *RTFM*.

Comment: Of course there is, they'd be totally useless otherwise. Did you read https://angular.io/guide/pipes?

Comment: Actually the post you provided has a answer for your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-use-pipes-in-services-and-components, look for the one with 8 answers.

Answer (score 0):

// ListConcatPipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'listConcat'
})
export class ListConcatPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(list: any[], seperator:any) {
        let str = "";
        list.forEach(element => {
            str = str + element + seperator;
        });
        return decodeURIComponent(str);
    }

}
```

// html template goes like this

```
<span class="vmiddle">Destination path : {{user}}/plans &amp; specs/{{uploadPath | listConcat : "/"}}</span>
```

// Module declarations go like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ListConcatPipe } from './list-concat.pipe';
import { Component } from './projects.compoennt';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [ListConcatPipe, Component],
    exports: [Component]
})

export class PipesModule { }
```