# Formatting Date in Angular without the time

Tags: angular, date

In my component I pass the following values to the controls. The value I pass are both of type date.

```
this.form.controls["DepartureDate"].setValue(this.flightChoice.departureDate);
this.form.controls["ReturnDate"].setValue(this.flightChoice.returnDate);
```

**The controls are of type Text**
because if I use type date the value are not written at all.

```
<input class="form-control" formControlName="DepartureDate" type="text" id="departureDate" />
<input class="form-control" formControlName="ReturnDate" type="text" id="returnDate" />
```

Now the result of passing the values is:
a date such this:
`2018-06-30T00:00:00+02:00`
when I would like a date such:
`30-06-2018`
What can I do to have this kind of value and also why using the input of type `date` will not accept my values?

Comment: You can use any pipe also in Typescript by providing it in the module and injecting it into the component just like any other service.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35144821/5118766

Answer (score 0):

Here is your 
[solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p15nvr)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, } from '@angular/forms';
import moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  dateForm: FormGroup;
  depDate: any;
  retDate: any

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createDateForm();
  }

  createDateForm() {
    this.dateForm = this.fb.group({
      DepartureDate: null,
      ReturnDate: null
    });
  }

  chageDepartureDate() {
    this.depDate = moment(this.dateForm.get('DepartureDate').value).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
  }

  changeReturnDate(event) {
    this.retDate = moment(this.dateForm.get('ReturnDate').value).format("DD-MM-YYYY");

  }
});

  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="dateForm">
    <p>Departure Date</p>
    <input (change)="chageDepartureDate($event)" type="date" formControlName="DepartureDate" placeholder="choose departure date">
    <p>Return Date</p>
    <input (change)="changeReturnDate($event)" type="date" formControlName="ReturnDate" placeholder="choose departure date">
</form>

<p>Departure Date = {{depDate}}</p>
<p>Return Date = {{retDate}}</p>
```