# How to get date and time in mm-dd-yyy hh-mm-ss in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, angular5

Currently, I am getting date time in the following format 'mm/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss'.
How to get it in the following format 'mm-dd-yyyy hh-mm-ss'.

How to achieve this without using any library, and preferably by passing some args to the function itself?

Below is the code that am currently using (in Angular 5)

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString(undefined, { hour12: false }));
```

Comment: Hi, the solution to the question you provided is the one that I am using in the first place. However, I want to format THAT output to a particular format, without the use of momentjs or writing any particular formatting function. Thanks :)

Comment: @GONZALOPANIAGUA - its not duplicate , its question for angular and angular has DatePipe for doing such formating ..no need of long javascript code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make use of DatePipe , that is provided by angular framework

```
{{ strDate | date :'MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm-ss' }
```

or in code you can do like this

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
 selector: 'test-component',
  templateUrl: './test-component.component.html'
})
class TestComponent {

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  formatDate(date= new Date()) {
    return this.datePipe.transform(date,'MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm-ss' );
  }
}
```

check here : [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: I tried this, but its throwing the error "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0" in DatePipe(). Any help?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35152297/3558960) has the information you need. TL;DR: inject it in your component/service.

Comment: Thanks @Robby Cornelissen . Your input helped me solve the error.

Comment: Thanks @PranayRana for the solution.