# How to use pipes in Angular 4 reactive form ng-select

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular4-forms, angular-pipe

I can't use pipe inside reactive forms ng-select
Thanks you very much!

```
<ng-select [items]="startDatetimeList"          
       [value]="items | date:'shortTime'"
       formControlName="estPickupStartTime">
```

Comment: Inject DatePipe and use it from the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-use-pipes-in-services-and-components/35144872

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - Use pipes in services and components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-use-pipes-in-services-and-components)