# Time format in angular 6

Tags: angular, pipe, angular6, time-format

I want to format time in angular 6 in html file...i  am writing this for now but it is not working.

```
<h5>{{"14:25:23" | date:'hh:mm a'}}</h5>
```

Any one can suggest or any answer how can i do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were looking for [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe), here a link to your answer I just found in slack [see this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-use-pipes-in-services-and-components?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing wrong with pipe. The only thing you have to change is your data format:

```
<h5>{{"2019-01-01T14:25:23" | date:'hh:mm a'}}</h5>
```

The output will be `02:25 PM`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
{{ dateObj | date:'medium' }}
```

It's Working :)