# How to get the resultant array after a pipe has been applied in angular?

Tags: html, angular

How do I get the transformed array in my component.ts file after "|" has been applied? Please help.

Comment: Just apply the pipe in the component...

Comment: this might helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-use-pipes-in-services-and-components

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply the pipe in the component.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35152297/3623608) you can find an example using the date pipe like this:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

class MyService {

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  transformDate(date) {
    return this.datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  }
}
```

Depending on your pipe you need to modify the code to your own needs.