# formcontrol value conversion in datepicker

Tags: angular, angular6

How to convert  dateFrom=Mon Dec 24 2018 05:30:00 GMT+0530 into dd-mm-yy in angular.component.ts

```
     <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Valid From*" [formControl]="dateFrom">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker  touchUi="true" #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-use-pipes-in-services-and-components

Comment: This is not duplicated

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in date pipe in your component as a service,

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

class MyService {

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  transformDate(date) {
    return this.datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add DatePipe to your module providers section:

```
providers: [DatePipe]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom formatter, something e.g. provided by `moment.js`. An example on [this page](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings) of Material Datepicker docs says how to do this, essentially you import moment and build a custom provider for your component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {MomentDateAdapter} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';

// Depending on whether rollup is used, moment needs to be imported differently.
// Since Moment.js doesn't have a default export, we normally need to import using the `* as`
// syntax. However, rollup creates a synthetic default module and we thus need to import it using
// the `default as` syntax.
import * as _moment from 'moment';
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-duplicate-imports
import {default as _rollupMoment} from 'moment';

const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;

// See the Moment.js docs for the meaning of these formats:
// https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

/** @title Datepicker with custom formats */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-formats-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-formats-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-formats-example.css'],
  providers: [
    // `MomentDateAdapter` can be automatically provided by importing `MomentDateModule` in your
    // application's root module. We provide it at the component level here, due to limitations of
    // our example generation script.
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})
export class DatepickerFormatsExample {
  date = new FormControl(moment());
}
```

You have more examples in the docs.