# Convert ddmmyyyy HH:mm to dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm in Angular6

Tags: angular, datetime, angular6, datetime-format

The date format which I am getting from the Api response is like this.

```
"startDate" : "07112018 00:00".
```

I want to convert this to in dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm format. that is like this `07-11-2018 00:00.`
Can anyone please tell me how to do this using Angular 6.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DatePipe API for this: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

```
@Component({
 selector: 'date-pipe',
 template: `<div>
   <p>Today is {{today | date}}</p>
   <p>Or if you prefer, {{today | date:'fullDate'}}</p>
   <p>The time is {{today | date:'h:mm a z'}}</p> //format in this line
 </div>`
})
// Get the current date and time as a date-time value.
export class DatePipeComponent {
  today: number = Date.now();
}
```

and this is what actually you want:

```
{{myDate | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```

**Edit:** **Using built-in pipe in component**,

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

class MyService {

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  transformDate(date) {
    return this.datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  }
}
```

Please read this topic, I took example from there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35152297/5955138

**Edit2:**
As I described in comment, you can substring your date using this.

```
var str = '07112018'
var d = new Date(str.substring(0, 2)+'.'+str.substring(2, 4)+'.'+str.substring(4, 8));
```

> Output: Wed Jul 11 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300

Comment: But i want to convert that and get the value in .ts file. Not in html file. How to do that in .ts file @shadowman_93

Comment: Can you please give detailed information, what do you get as error ?

Comment: Yes, this error i am getting. InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "02112018 00:00" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Comment: i am doing like this.
var startdate = this.datePipe.transform('02112018 00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm');

console.log("startdate"+ startdate);

Comment: Can you tell me if "07112018 00:00" this is correct format of sending data ?

Comment: @ananya that does not look like a valid date format. You can try using `new Date('02112018 00:00')` to verify. You should provide the date in a valid format.

Comment: @ananya I've updated my answer as Seiyria told above.

Answer (score 0):

try this function to convert time format as you require

```
timeFormetChange(){
 var date =new Date();
 var newDate = date.getDate();
 var newMonth = date.getMonth();
 var newYear =date.getFullYear();
 var Hour = data.getHours();
 var Minutes = data.getMinuets();
 return `${newDate}-${newMonth }-${newYear} ${Hour}:${Minutes }`
}
```