# How to use slice inside the .ts file?

Tags: angular

In my html, I used pipe
`{{dat.url.split(":")[1]|slice:2}}`(Template file).This is how I showed the data from the database.

The DB data is like **http://192.168.103.42:8888**.

But I should show the data like 192.168.103.42 from this.

The problem is, when the user selects the edit option, by default it should show their saved data. For that I have to again use this 
`dat.url.split(":")[1]|slice:2` in my .ts file(form field).

But it shows error in slice:2

How to use slice inside .ts file in angular?

Comment: Please use like this [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-use-pipes-in-services-and-components)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
 let temp = this.dat.url.substring(this.dat.url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

 this.dat.url = temp.substr(0, temp.lastIndexOf(":"));
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s6mrfl)**

Comment: Thanks for your help.But it shows Iike 192.168.103.42:9999.But I need only 192.168.103.42.

Comment: Check the modified answer

Comment: It works.But can you please give me the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Also you may try this:

```
 this.dat.url = this.dat.url.split(":")[1].slice(2)
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n9sq6c)

Comment: It works too.But if I use this,it shows error at [Validators.required].Thanks for your help

Comment: There should be no mistake. Full code is needed to determine the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is a super set of Javascript. So slicing is same as you do in JavaScript.

1st method is using slice()

```
var str = 'unbelievable';
// pass (zero-based) index location 2 to slice
var str2 = str.slice(2);
console.log(str2); // believable
```

2nd method is using substring()

```
var str = 'unbelievable';
var str2 = str.substring(2);
console.log( str2 ); // believable
```

3rd method is using substr()

```
var str = 'unbelievable';
var str2 = str.substr(2);
console.log(str2); // believable
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can use regex for this

```js
let url = "http://192.168.103.42:8888"
let trimed = url.replace(/:[^:]+$/, "");
console.log(trimed);
```