# When is it useful to inject a custom pipe?

Tags: angular

According to the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes):

> If you choose to inject your pipe into a class, you must provide it in the providers array of your NgModule.

Given `exponential-strength.pipe.ts`:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'exponentialStrength' })
export class ExponentialStrengthPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, exponent?: number): number {
    return Math.pow(value, isNaN(exponent) ? 1 : exponent);
  }
}
```

I am able to use this custom pipe in a template by adding the declaration to `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ExponentialStrengthPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
```

E.G. in `app.component.html`

```
<div>
  {{ 2 | exponentialStrength:10 }}
</div>
```

I'm confused by Angular's documentation.  It doesn't mention the need to add the custom pipe to `declarations` in the documentation.  The documentation only mentions `providers`.

Is it useful in some cases to inject a pipe when the declaration works just fine?  I'm having trouble imagining a use case where I would actually put a pipe into `providers` array.  And would I still need to define the custom pipe in `declarations` in such a case?

Comment: Declaring it as a provider gives you the ability to use it inside the component's class or a service (using dependency injection) instead of just the template.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35152297/9901630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs state if you want to inject a pipe in your component to use as a service, you need to add it to the providers. This could come of use, if you want to use certain functions in your pipe (which you better just move to a util file).

For all intents and purposes you should not add it to the providers, unless you are a bit lazy :)