# convert 2020-02-17 to ddd, MMM Do YYYY in angular

Tags: angular, pipe, momentjs

Hi am trying to convert convert `2020-02-17` to (`ddd, MMM Do YYYY`) using moment.js

```
 transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    console.log(value)
    console.log(moment(value).format("ddd, MMM Do YYYY"))
    return moment(value).format("ddd, MMM Do YYYY");
  }
```

i have created a pipe for it but it is returning me the value based on current date
can somebody help

Comment: Could you please create a StackBlitz sample for the same? Also the cases you tested.

Comment: why not use date pipe angular? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-use-pipes-in-services-and-components: `new DatePipe().transform(new Date(value), 'ddd, MMM yyyy');`

Answer (score 0):

This should be working, as you can see on this example : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kuxqmrtn/)

```
transform(value: any, args ?: any): any {
  return moment(value).format("ddd, MMM Do YYYY");
}
```

So your transform pipe should return `Mon, Feb 17th 2020`.

See [Angular Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sngvoz?file=src/app/moment-date.pipe.ts).

Answer (score 0):

This happens if your value is sent blank or null check your value again.