# How to use angular 9 $localize with plurals?

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

Since Angular 9 we can use

```js
$localize`Hello ${name}:name:`
```

For i18n in typescript code. This still has some limitations as the `ng xi18n` command does not detect the strings, but if these texts are added manually to the translation file it works.

The `$localize` function is quite well documented in the [JSDoc in the source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/99ce015f42a7a59636705a901f52228c3f287890/packages/localize/src/localize/src/localize.ts#L47), however it does not explain how to work with plurals. What I mean is something like this (pseudo-code):

```js
$localize`Hello {${count}, plural, =1 {reader} other {readers}}`
```

Is this possible with `$localize`? If yes: How? If no: How does Angular compile such expressions from HTML to TypeScript?

Comment: does this help you ```<span i18n>Updated {minutes, plural, =0 {just now} =1 {one minute ago} other {{{minutes}} minutes ago}}</span>``` ? Thats in the docs. Pretty similar to what you want

Comment: @DavePastor: Yes, I tried that. I changed that in the question now. Nevertheless it is pseudo-code, just to illustrate what I want to achieve.

Comment: @DavePastor: (concerning the second comment): No, this does not help. This is HTML, not TypeScript.

Comment: Ok so you want to handle this on the TS side. Got it.

Comment: Check this https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/12/10/angular-localize/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For now, it is not possible to use ICUs with `$localize`, as discussed in this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35912). From the last comments, it looks like angular team is considering it if it remains lightweight.

Meanwhile, the suggested workaround is to create your own helper method that returns the correct translation based on the count parameter.

```js
    title = $localize `Hi ${this.name}! You have ${
        plural(this.users.length. {
          0: $localize `no users`,
          1: $localize `one user`,
          other: $localize`${this.users.length} users`,
    }.`

    function plural(value, options) {
      // Handle 0, 1, ... cases
      const directResult = options[value];
      if (directResult !== undefined) { return directResult; }
      // handle zero, one, two, few, many
      // ...
      return options.other;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I've just read issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35912 and I think that `intl-messageformat` can do what you need.

See https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/tree/master/packages/intl-messageformat.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested in 2023, you don't have to use a separate library to achieve this feature. I've found a workaround using the [i18nPluralPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/I18nPluralPipe).

First of all follow the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35152297/6330843), to get the i18nPluralPipe working in your module.

In your desired component use Angular DI and inject the following:

```js
...
constructor(
    private i18nPluralPipe: I18nPluralPipe,
    @Inject(LOCALE_ID) private _locale: string) {}
...
```

when you want to translate a message:

```js
...
    const plural = this.i18nPluralPipe.transform(
      numericVariable,
      {
        '=0': $localize`No results found.`,
        '=1': $localize`One result found.`,
        'other': $localize`${numericVariable} results found.`
      },
      this._locale
    );

   // do what you want with this pluralized variable
   console.log(plural);
...
```

Don't forget to generate the translations using `ng extract-i18n`!