# How to use the angular decimal pipe in typscript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I'm using the [angular decimal pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#description) like this:

```
// Typescript
@Component({...})
export class ConfusionMatrixComponent {

    @Input()
    roundRules = '1.0-2';
}

// HTML:
<div class="value">{{ getIntensityNumber(i) | number: roundRules }}</div>
```

How can I use the same pipe but on a typescript function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - Use pipes in services and components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-use-pipes-in-services-and-components)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found in a [similar question](http://Angular%20-%20Use%20pipes%20in%20services%20and%20components) how to use it: just need to import `DecimalPipe` from `@angular/commun` and use it as a service:

```
// Typescript
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({...})
export class ConfusionMatrixComponent {

    @Input()
    roundRules = '1.0-2';

    constructor(private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) { }

    getRoundNumber(num: number): string | null {
        return this.decimalPipe.transform(num, this.roundRules) ?? '0';
    }

}

// HTML:
<div class="value">{{ getRoundNumber(23.50873) }}</div>
```

Also, make sure you add the DecimalPipe to your `providers` angular module:

```
import { CommonModule, DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [CommonModule],
    exports: [...],
    providers: [DecimalPipe]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ng dependency injection.

Make sure to import the module and add `DecimalPipe` to the providers array.

```
providers: [DecimalPipe,...]
```

And then in your component.

```
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

class MyService {
  constructor(private _decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {}

  transformDecimal(num) {
    return this._decimalPipe.transform(num, '1.2-2');
  }
}
```

An alternative approach to `decimalPipe` is [formatNumber](https://angular.io/api/common/formatNumber)