# How to use datepipe outside of a component.ts in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a typescript file used to export some constant variables (export const). I would like to use `datepipe` to format date in the ts file, but I do not know how to add service to use `datepipe` in a non component ts file.

For example:

```
export const dateObject = [
  {
    value: {
      start: new Date(),
      end: new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 10),
    },
    title: 'Ten Years Later'
  }
];
```

How can I make `datepipe.transform(, 'yyyy-MM-dd')` work in this typescript?

Thank you!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - Use pipes in services and components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-use-pipes-in-services-and-components)

Comment: not really, I know how to use datepipe in export class. But I would like to know how to use a service in export const.

Comment: @WenliL That distinction is not relevant: to use a pipe virtually anywhere outside a template, you just import it and call its `.transform()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

export const dateObject = [{
  value: {
    start: new DatePipe('en-US').transform(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
    end: new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 10),
  },
  title: 'Ten Years Later',
}];
```

Comment: got error: An argument for 'locale' was not provided.

Comment: DatePipe() function expects a 'locale' string argument that needs to be passed with it. Adding a locale value will resolve the error. Here's the fix - new DatePipe('en-US')

Comment: Please see the updated answer. As pointed by @Pushpak, you need to provide the locale.

Comment: Thank you! It works.

Answer (score 2):

```
new DatePipe(navigator.language || 'en-US').transform(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```