# Angular 2 not working in chrome on iPhone 6

Tags: angular

I am developing Angular 2 responsive website. It's working fine when I view it in the Chrome browser and by setting the device type to any of the devices e.g. iPhone 6.

But when I test it on my iPhone 6 device in Chrome it doesn't load properly. Some of the functionality simply doesn't work. As an example I have a list of items and only the first item loads with some data and the rest of the items only load css without data. The same thing happends in Firefox and Safari on iPhone 6.

Unfortunately I cannot see if there are any errors in Chrome on my mobile device since there is no debugger mode. I am using Angular 2 RC5 and angular-cli is serving from my local 192.xxx ip address.

Any idea why Angular works in the chrome simulator but not on my device?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem was with a missing polyfill.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017800/ionic-2-using-angular-2-pipe-breaks-on-ios-cant-find-variable-intl