# Date formatter is not working when using with ionic and angular v2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have following code snippet :

home.html :

```
 <ion-item>
       <ion-label>Date:</ion-label>
       <ion-label class="alignme">{{todayDate | date: "MM/dd/yy" }}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
```

home.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

this.todayDate = new Date();

}
```

While loading application on device it is showing blank screen . When i remove pipe from todayDate , it's showing current date value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 2, Using Angular 2 Pipe breaks on iOS—"Can't find variable: Intl"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017800/ionic-2-using-angular-2-pipe-breaks-on-ios-cant-find-variable-intl)

Comment: john, thanks for your update , but it did not work by using shared link.

Comment: Check my answer, let me know if it solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `intl` package (or update package.json):

```
npm install intl
```

In `polyfill.ts` or `main.ts`

```
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en.js';
```

Tested and working for Safari.