# Ionic-Angular binding not removing DOM element, null number format causes binding to fail

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a binding to a variable:

```
<span *ngIf="myVoltage && myVoltage>=0" > - {{myVoltage | number: '.0-0'}}</span>
```

According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html):

> **ngIf**
>   Removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}.

'myVoltage' is null because it gets retrieved from the server, hence if `{{myVoltage | number: '.0-0'}}` executed it would throw some kind of null exception. That is why I have it in a *span*:

```
<span *ngIf="myVoltage && myVoltage>=0" >...</span>
```

However it **STILL** executes the binding and formatting on the object inside the span EVEN though it shouldn't because the span should not be visible!

> EXCEPTION: null is not an object (evaluating 'new Intl.NumberFormat(e,u)')

If I remove the `| number: '.0-0'` then it will display fine. However as-is the null exception actually causes the binding to break and then it will NEVER display even when the value is not null any more.

My setup information:

> Cordova CLI: 6.2.0 
>   Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.1 
>   Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8 
>   Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4 
>   Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.30 
>   ios-deploy version: 1.9.0  
>   ios-sim version: 5.0.11  
>   OS: macOS Sierra 
>   Node Version: v6.7.0 
>   Xcode version: Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.0.3",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "ionic-native": "2.0.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "2.14.1",
    "ng2-translate": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.30",
    "i18next-conv": "3.0.3",
    "typescript": "2.0.6"
  },
```

I have also tried:

```
*ngIf="!!busVoltage && busVoltage>=0"
[ngIf]="busVoltage && busVoltage>=0"
```

**EDIT 1**

So according to the [Angular 2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html) this is the right way of doing things:

```
<!-- because of the ngIf guard
nullHero.firstName never has a chance to fail -->
<div *ngIf="nullHero">Hello, {{nullHero.firstName}}</div>
```

**EDIT 2**

So according the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/1608d91728af707d9740756a80e78cfb1148dd5a/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.ts#L82):

> /**
>    * WARNING: this pipe uses the Internationalization API.
>    * Therefore it is only reliable in Chrome and Opera browsers. For other browsers please use an
>    * polyfill, for example: [https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/].

And according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35018352/932052) I need to add the "intl" library, but I have used NPM, and I am not sure where to put the following:

```
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar issue, which we resolved with the following workaround: We implemented a custom pipe which used [JavaScript's native formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342819(v=vs.94).aspx):

```
if(value === null) {
    return "";
}
Intl.NumberFormat().format(value);
```

The elegance of this is that we removed the burden of formatting from the view plus I think in your case it will remove the pipe chaining.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!